# Pathname from the prop history.location of the Router doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to develop a web system using React Router DOM, I follow exactly how it is explained on their documentation and live examples. But the prop history.location.pathname of the router, is always '/', when I change it manually (React Developer Tool), it works, but when I just go through the URL or a Link component, don't work.

[router props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Yqx.png)

//routes file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRedirect, IndexRoute, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Index from "./index.jsx";
import UserAddress from "./UserAddress.jsx";

var routes = () => (    
    <div>
        <Switch>        
            <Route exact path="/" component={()=>(<h1>Teste</h1>)} key="1"/>
            <Route path="/home" component={UserAddress} key="2"/>
            <Route path="/userAddress" component={UserAddress} key="3"/>            
            {/*<IndexRedirect to="login" />*/}          
            {/*<Route path="login" component={Login} />*/}      
        </Switch>
    </div>  
);

ReactDOM.render((
        <Router>
            <Index children={routes}/>
        </Router>
    ),
    document.getElementById('container')
);

module.exports = true;
```

//component file

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Index extends React.Component {  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    /*this.propTypes = {
      onBook: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };*/
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <header className="bh-header navbar navbar-static-top">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img alt="Brand" className="bh-logo" src="//behive.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DEFAULT-CURRENT-LOGO-01-e1479943327763.png"/>
          </a>
          <a className="bh-log-out">
            <label>Log out</label>
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"/>
          </a>
        </header>
        <div className="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
          <div className="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul className="nav" id="side-menu">
              <li className="sidebar-search">
                  <div className="input-group custom-search-form">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
                      <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-default" type="button">
                          <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                      </span>
                  </div>                  
              </li>
              <li>
                  <Link to="#/userAddress">
                    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> {" User Address"}
                  </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <Link to="#">
                    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i>
                      {"  Charts"}
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>
                  </Link>
                  <ul className="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                      <li>
                          <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <article className="panel panel-default bh-content-container">          
          {this.props.children()}
        </article>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router defines path as normal path(as `path="/home"`). So you `<Link/>` component should point to exact same path.

Try

```
<Link to="/">
<Link to="/home">
<Link to="/userAddress">
```

By using `<Link to="#/userAddress">` you are changing `hash` parameter, which can be seen in `hash` props.